# Perl regex script and command line different

Tags: regex, perl, command-line

So I am trying to remove embedded \n from log lines without removing the \n for each log line from command line.
I have tried these and they all changed all \n to ~.

```
    cat test1.txt | perl -n -e 's{\n(?!2013)}{~}mg;print' > test1a.fix
    perl -n -e 's{\n(?!2013)}{~}mg;print' test1.txt > test1b.fix
```

All ignore the negative look behind.

test1.txt contains

```
    2013-03-01 12:23:59,1
    line2
        line3
    2013-03-01 12:23:59,4
```

test1a.fix and test1b.fix contained

```
    2013-03-01 12:23:59,1~line2~    line3~2013-03-01 12:23:59,4
```

But I came up with the regex using this script.

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    use warnings;
    use strict;

    sub test {
        my ($str, $expect) = @_;
        my $mod = $str;
        $mod =~ s{\n(?!2013)}{~}mg;
        print "Expecting '$expect' got '$mod' - ";
        print $mod eq $expect ? "passed\n" : "failed\n";
    }

    test("2013-03-01 12:23:59,line1
    line2
        line3
    2013-03-01 12:23:59,line4", "2013-03-01 12:23:59,line1~line2~    line3
    2013-03-01 12:23:59,line4");
```

and it produces the following output that matches what I want.

```
    sfager@linux-sz05:~/logs> ./regex_test.pl 
    Expecting '2013-03-01 12:23:59,line1~line2~    line3
    2013-03-01 12:23:59,line4' got '2013-03-01 12:23:59,line1~line2~    line3
    2013-03-01 12:23:59,line4' - passed
    sfager001@linux-sz05:~/logs>
```

Can anyone explain why these work differently and how this can be done on the command line?

Answer (score 4):

`perl -n` processes the file one line at a time. When it reads a line, the newline is at the end of the string, not the beginning as your regexp expects. You should use `^` to match the beginning of the line rather than `\n`.

In the function version, you're processing the entire multi-line string at once. In this case,  the newlines are in the middle of the string, and they match the regexp.

Answer (score 2):

Your command line program only sees one "input record" (a.k.a. line) at a time.
I was able to get your example working by stomping the input record separator variable $/.

```
perl -n -e '$/=undef; s{\n(?!2013)}{~}mg;print' test1.txt > test1c.fix
```

This redefines each "line" to be the entire input and in effect gets it to work more like your script.

```
cat test1c.fix
2013-03-01 12:23:59,1~line2~    line3
2013-03-01 12:23:59,4~
```

Comment: thanks searched for multi-line option for command line perl and found the -0777 flag and that make this work correctly. 

        perl -0777 -n -e 's{\n(?!2013)}{~}mg;print' test1.txt > test1c.fix
thanks all

Comment: I learned something here. (From perl --help: -0[octal] specify record separator)